# Flow: Required field is missing: connector

Tags: visual-workflow

**Given**

- Autolaunched flow with Pause element as shown in picture

[image]

**When**

- Save

**Then**

- Get error: `Required field is missing: connector`

What is the `connector` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in a simple flow as shown above, the suspicion goes to the `Pause` element and, in fact, what is missing is a resume element for the non-default path `Pause Condition`.  Adding some element after the resume time elapses allows the Flow to be saved.

[image]

Note that upon successful Save, if you then save a new version of the flow and delete the resume element, you get a useful error message as shown below.  It is only on the initial save of the Pause element without resume element that the error message is "unhelpful" and might be hard to find in a flow with many more elements and paths.

[image]